# Localize my DataModel stuff asp.net

Tags: asp.net, localization

so i have a multi-tier web app in asp.net mvc i use the asp.net localization with resource files, and it's ok for pages, but i have also some messages (not in the UI) how do i localize the stuff that is in other class libraries ?

Comment: I have found Michele Leroux Bustamante's BLogs on this to be very helpful.  

http://www.dasblonde.net/CategoryView,category,Globalization.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution, it's very easy, I have put the resource files in a separate class library and everybody knows the current language though CurrentThread.UICulture